# Dynamically set renderer_class in DRF

Tags: django-rest-framework

How can i dynamically set the `renderer_class` in DRF from a request query parameter?

I know that DRF chooses the `renderer_class` based on ACCEPT header but the client has requested an option to select the class based on GET query parameter

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be achieved by overwriting the `get_format_suffix` function on a view.

```
class MyView(APIView):

    format_suffix = 'format'

    def get_format_suffix(self, **kwargs):
        return self.request.query_params.get(self.format_suffix)
```